# How could be best set up a help feature for repairs in Africa?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Ooops: I just got my last question blocked for being off-topic. I am sorry, I had not realized that this exchange is only meant for design of electrical stuff, not for installation, operating nor repair questions. So please disregard this meta question. And if you want to be kind, please point me to a good quality repair forum. I am an engineer myself, but often need help with documentation or with input from the experience in specific areas like pumps or power supplies. Thanks, sorry, greetings. Over and out. Martin

I repeatedly have "weird" questions but do not want to abuse this helpful exchange. Normally asking "What capacity can I use to replace...?" or "What is the lowest voltage I can operate a freezer on?" are bad engineering.

But here in Africa we got special context conditions: Shipments of spare parts typically take several weeks and are very expensive in postage and customs, there is a certain risk of loss for any parcel too.

Also just ordering spare parts often does not help until there is some minimal understanding of the problem or even a diagnosis. Here in West Africa we have very few fully trained and equipped electricians. And the public power supply is erratic and often voltage is low or fluctuating.

Also sometimes I might need help even finding certain parts by mail order, which are not typical "end user maintenance parts", like components for pumps or special relais. The user manual often says "do not open, do not try to repair" but not to try would be lame and creating much more electrical scrap.

Still, many local offices and projects are providing valuable services to the population and running a machine (pump, printer, hospital gear) or not running it will have an impact. As there is zero recycling appart from the metal by the kilo, any machine that cannot be repaired is a financial loss and a burden to the environment.

So I am looking for members who:

a) are willing to answer weird or exotic questions, even if they would not be considered "good" or "mainstream" on this site

b) have spent time in Africa or similar places and can allow for not-helpful context in any given purchase or repair question - or can guide me and other local users in how to improve our questions or how to provide extra needed information

And I would like help (maybe a special tag for Africa) which would "protect" such questions from being penalized for being "different".

I believe I could set up a fresh StackExchange unit just for Africa Electrical, but the title might frighten many otherwise competent users and we would have much less reach...

Please let me know what you think and how or if this sort of help can happen here. I have seen some "funny" questions on the other end of the spectrum, like "I want to plug four not-small ventilators by USB on my laptop, how can I boost the voltage (and power) of my USB...?" which sounds like a kid having fun and not wanting to spend 25 dollars on a regular cooling pad - and still such questions are getting helpful and graceful answers, which is nice.

Answer (score 3):

Most of your questions seem to be about mains power and appliances that operate from it, topics that would be more suitable for [Home Improvement.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest), a site devoted to contractors and serious DIYers.